# Error when deserializing enum on c# datacontract

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have the following DataContract: Note: I don't have permission on changing the DataContract. I'm only referencing on it.

```
 [Serializable]
 [DataContract]
 public class Client
 {
     public Client();
 [DataMember]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
 public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
 }
```

And in the Contact:

```
 [Serializable]
 [DataContract]
 public class Contact
 {
      public Contact();
 [DataMember]
 public string ContactName { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
 public ContactTypes ContactType { get; set; }
 }
```

The ContactTypes is an enum:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public enum ContactTypes
{
     [EnumMember(Value="Phone")]
     Phone = 1,

     [EnumMember(Value="Mail")]
     Mail = 2
}
```

My problem is when i'm deserializing my xml. It is showing an error: Invalid enum value "1" cannot be deserialized.

Here is my xml:

```
 <Clients>
 <Client>
      <Name>Firstname</Name>
      <Contacts>
           <Contact>
               <ContactName>ContactName</ContactName>
               <ContactType>1</ContactType>
           </Contact>
      </Contacts>
</Client>
</Clients>
```

Did I missed something here? I've been stock on this problem the whole day now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the data contract includes enumeration member names, not numerical values. When using the data contract model, if the receiving side is a WCF client, the exported schema preserves the numerical value.

This only *easy way* to solve it to change the datacontract in this way

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public enum ContactTypes
{
     [EnumMember(Value="1")]
     Phone = 1,

     [EnumMember(Value="2")]
     Mail = 2
}
```

Now if you can't edit the datacontract, you may have a big problem...

I suppose the sending side is not using WCF (why locking datacontract ? why a bad definition ? ), and it's really important to use the correct data contract model : it's not adapted to the xml file.

Comment: The truth is I can edit the datacontract but on my local end only. I supposed I will give this a shot.